# Blocks retaining the class they just got passed to?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks

We have a class that wraps NSURLConnection. It accepts a block that it calls back when it finishes loading. To give you an idea, see below. When you send a request, it saves the callback on the instance. Assume my class is named `Request`

```
// from Request.h
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^callback)(Request*);
- (void) sendWithCallback:(void(^)(Request*))callback;
```

My code to use one looks something like this:

```
Request * request = [Request requestWithURL:url];
[request sendWithCallback:^(Request * request) {
    // do some stuff
}]
```

My question is: what does the block do to the retain count of `request`? Does it copy/retain it? Notice that I didn't put `__block` in front of the definition.

I just changed something major in `Request` (switched from a synchronous `NSURLConnection` to async `ASIHTTPRequest`), and it started deallocing almost immediately after sending (causing delegate methods to call a dealloced object). With the sync `NSURLConnection`, that never happened.

I guess it makes sense that it would get dealloced with async, but how would I retain `request` appropriately? If I retained it right after I created it, I'd have to release it in the callback, but the callback doesn't get called if the request is cancelled, and would create a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does the block do to the retain count of request? Does it copy/retain it?

No, it doesn't.

```
Request * request = [Request requestWithURL:url];
[request sendWithCallback:^(Request * request) {
    // The request argument shadows the request local variable,
    // this block doesn't retain the request instance.
}]
```

If the block doesn't have the request argument,

```
Request * request = [Request requestWithURL:url];
[request sendWithCallback:^{
    // If you use the request local variable in this block,
    // this block automatically retains the request instance.
}]
```

In this case, it would cause retain cycles (the request retains the block, the block retains the request).

- [AsyncURLConnection.h](https://gist.github.com/905151)
- [AsyncURLConnection.m](https://gist.github.com/905154)

Please take a look at my AsyncURLConnection class. NSURLConnection retains AsyncURLConnection instance, so you don't own AsyncURLConnection stuff by yourself.

How to use

```
[AsyncURLConnection request:url completeBlock:^(NSData *data) {
    // Do success stuff
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // Do error stuff
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Blocks won’t automatically retain or copy object arguments. It’s the same semantics as passing object arguments to methods or functions — the block, method, or function should retain its arguments if there’s potential for the current autorelease pool to drain before the block, method, or function has finished using the arguments.

Note the workflow in your scenario. This code:

```
Request * request = [Request requestWithURL:url];
[request sendWithCallback:^(Request * request) {
    // do some stuff
}];
```

does not execute the block yet, nor does it pass any argument to the block. It creates a block and passes it as an argument to `-sendWithCallback:`. The block has a parameter called `request` of type `Request *` but the actual argument hasn’t been passed yet.

At some point later in your code, and assuming you’ve stored the block in `callback`, that block will be called as:

```
callback(someRequest); // or callback(self);
```

or

```
self.callback(someRequest); // or self.callback(self);
```

or

```
aRequest.callback(someRequest); // or someRequest.callback(someRequest);
```

depending on who’s responsible for calling it. At this point, whoever calls the callback should have a reference to a valid request (`someRequest`), and that request is the argument passed to the block.